# Spark collect_set vs distinct

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If my goal is to collect distinct values in a column as a list, is there a performance difference or pros/cons using either of these?

```
df.select(column).distinct().collect()...
```

vs

```
df.select(collect_set(column)).first()...
```

Answer (score 4):

`collect_set` is an aggregator function and requires a `groupBy` in the beginning. When there is no grouping provided it will take entire data as 1 big group.

#### 1. collect_set

```scala
df.select(collect_set(column)).first()...
```

This will send all data of column `column` to a single node which will perform `collect_set` operation (removing duplicates). If your data size is big then it will swamp the single executor where all data goes.

#### 2. distinct

```scala
df.select(column).distinct().collect()...
```

This will partition all data of column `column` based on its value (called partition key), no. of partitions will be the value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (say 200). So 200 tasks will execute to remove duplicates, 1 for each partition key. Then only dedup data will be sent to the driver for `.collect()` operation. This will fail if your data after removing duplicates is huge, will cause driver to go out of memory.

#### TLDR:

`.distinct` is better than `.collect_set` for your `specific` need

Comment: Thanks Samir! Where can I find documentation on how these functions say collect_set are performed under the hood?
I initially expected that each partition on various nodes would collect a set aka dedup most of the data and then bubble up in a map reduce manner to a single node to dedup further until reach one node in this case in order not to overload that single node.